# Is there a place to find other jQuery UI themes?

Tags: jquery-ui, themeroller

For some reason i don't like any of the themes that are on the jquery ui themeroller page (i am looking for something on a business website and these all look either bleak or too corny).  I wanted to see if there were other sites where people have uploaded or voted on other themes to view and download.

I know i can tweak my own but first wanted to see if anyone has done this already with a better artistic eye.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348559/are-there-hosted-jquery-ui-themes-anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aristo](http://www.warfuric.com/taitems/demo.html) is a really nice jQuery UI theme that is worth consideration.

As others have mentioned, there are more themes out there if want to do some more digging...